# Letter spacing in Flash dynamic textfield

Tags: flash, dynamic, textbox

Letter spacing doesn't seen to work for dynamic text fields in Flash. I use CS4 on Mac, player version 10.0.2. Does it also depend on the font that's used?

Comment: btw, it works in the IDE but it doesn't work in the .swf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Letterspacing works only with embedded fonts and for dynamic textFields set the `defaultTextFormat`.

Comment: Do you mean embedded characters? I have done it. But still not working. Am i missing something?

Comment: Yes, thats what i mean. Has the default text also no spacing or only text you set later to the textfield?

Comment: The default text is properly spaced. Only the dynamic loaded text that's not spaced.

Comment: then you have to set the textformat again after applying the text or set a default textformat `textField.defaultTextFormat = new TextFormat(...)`